# Looping through an array of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm a total Perl newbie, so forgive me if this is really stupid, but I can't figure this out. If I have an array like this:

```
my @array = (
  {username => 'user1', email => 'user1@email' },
  {username => 'user2', email => 'user2@email' },
  {username => 'user2', email => 'user3@email' }
);
```

What's the most simple way to loop through this array? I thought something like this would work:

```
print "$_{username} : $_{email}\n" foreach (@array);
```

But it doesn't. I guess I'm too stuck with a PHP mindset where I could just do something like:

```
foreach ($array as $user) { echo "$user['username'] : $user['email']\n"; }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`@array` contains hash *references*, so you need to use `->` to derefecence.

```
print "$_->{username} : $_->{email}\n" foreach (@array);
```

See also the documentation, for instance [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: Oh god, I feel so dumb now. Thank you!

Comment: also could be written `say "$$_{username} : $$_{email}" for @array;`